# Access denied on a script that should work

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an assignment that says: "Find out how many .bat and .cmd files there are on the C drive".
I got help from a classmate, and together we came to this:

```
Get-Childitem -path c:\ -include *.bat,*.cmd -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Measure-Object|select count
```

It works on his computer, but not on mine. And when I only check for .bat files it can work. And it doesn't work by putting *.bat and *.cmd in quotations

Error:

```
Get-Childitem : Adgang nægtet
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Childitem -path c:\ -include *.bat,*.cmd -Recurse -ErrorAction Si ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

And "Adgang nægtet" means Access denied :-)

Full error message:

```
Exception             : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Adgang nægtet ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
                     Adgang nægtet
                       --- Slut på staksporing af indre undtagelser ---
                       ved System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeDirectoryExists(String path)
                       ved System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider prov
                    iderInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context)
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are getting :)

Comment: as `I.T Delinquent` implied, the EXACT error msg can be quite important. please add that text - not an image - to your Original Post.

Comment: That's done now

Comment: Run the script with `administrator` priviliges

Comment: Can you use `$error[0]|format-list -force` and post expanded error version?

Comment: Side note: `-Include` and `-Recurse` together makes for a terribly slow script, `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File -Filter '*.???' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Where-Object Extension -in '.bat','.cmd'` would be much better